# debugging typescript in vscode with autorestart

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am setting up a typescript project with node.

I can debug my `main.ts` file in vs code with this `launch.json` configuration:

```
 {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Lancer le programme",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main.ts",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
        ]
    }
```

This works fine but there is no auto restart when I edit `main.ts`

To implement auto restart, I launch in my project directory `tsc --watch`, and then this lauch configuration:

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "nodemon",
        "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--debug=5858"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main.ts",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
        ],
        "restart": true,
        "port": 5858,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "sourceMaps": true
    },
```

The above configuration does autorestart when I edit source files, but the vscode debugger doesn't break anymore...

Has anyone achieved : debugging typscript in vscode with autorestart ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/index.js",
            "restart": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--debug=5858",
                "--inspect-brk"
            ],
            "port": 5858,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the prop `program` must indicate compiled js file. In your case it is `${workspaceRoot}/src/main.ts`, but should be `${workspaceRoot}/*compile directory eg. build*/main.js`.

Also make sure the typescript recompiles the files to the target directory.

Comment: Please, if applicable, try to describe what your config does and where it differs from the OPs one to make it easier to understand how your solution works

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` and `nodemon.json` look like? I am getting the `File 'dist/file.js' is a Javascript file. Did you mean to enable the 'allowJs' option?` message due to an error that says nodemon is attempting to start 'tsc ./dist/file.js' when it's supposed to compile and output to the src folder.